# Variance of a straddle (Black Scholes)

Tags: options, black-scholes, covariance, variance

I am trying to determine the variance of the payout of a straddle. For puts and calls individually:

```
Var[P] = E[P^2] - E[P]^2
Var[C] = E[C^2] - E[C]^2
```

where:
$$
E[P] \text = e^{-r T}\int _0{}^k\frac{(k-S) }{\sqrt{2 \pi } b S} e^{-\frac{(\log (S)-a)^2}{2 b^2}}dS
$$

$$
E[C] \text = e^{-r T}\int _k{}^{\infty}\frac{(S-k) }{\sqrt{2 \pi } b S} e^{-\frac{(\log (S)-a)^2}{2 b^2}}dS
$$
$$
E[P^2] \text = e^{-2r T}\int _0{}^k\frac{(k-S)^2 }{\sqrt{2 \pi } b S} e^{-\frac{(\log (S)-a)^2}{2 b^2}}dS
$$

$$
E[C^2] \text = e^{-2r T}\int _k{}^{\infty}\frac{(S-k)^2}{\sqrt{2 \pi } b S} e^{-\frac{(\log (S)-a)^2}{2 b^2}}dS
$$
Where:
$$
a=T \left(r-\frac{\sigma ^2}{2}\right)+\log \left(S_0\right)
$$
and
$$
b=\sigma  \sqrt{T}
$$

These results become:

$$
E[P] = k \Phi \left(-d_2\right) e^{-r T}-S_0 \Phi \left(-d_1\right)
$$
$$
E[C] = S_0 \Phi \left(d_1\right)-k \Phi \left(d_2\right) e^{-r T}
$$
$$
E[P^2] = k^2 \Phi \left(-d_2\right) e^{-2 r T}-2 k S_0 \Phi \left(-d_1\right) e^{-r T}+S_0^2 \Phi \left(d_2-2 d_1\right) e^{\sigma ^2 T}
$$
$$
E[C^2] = k^2 \Phi \left(d_2\right) e^{-2 r T}-2 k S_0 \Phi \left(d_1\right) e^{-r T}+S_0^2 \Phi \left(2 d_1-d_2\right) e^{\sigma ^2 T}
$$

Note that 
$$
d_1=\frac{-\log (k)+T \left(r-\frac{\sigma ^2}{2}\right)+\log \left(S_0\right)+\sigma ^2 T}{\sigma  \sqrt{T}}
$$
and
$$
d_2=d_1-\sigma  \sqrt{T}
$$

where:

```
S0 = initial price
S = price
k = strike
r = interest rate
T = time to expiration
sigma = implied volatility
Phi = standard normal variable
```

These results are also shown in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.3452.pdf

My question: how to combine Var[P] and Var[C] to get Var[straddle]?

Since C and P are negatively correlated(right?), can we use this?
$$
Var[straddle] = Var[P] + Var[C] - 2\sqrt{Var[P] Var[C] }
$$

This seems alright, I'm not sure. If we instead start with the payoff for the straddle as a piecewise function:
$$
payoff_{straddle} = \begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 k-S & 0<S<k \\
 S-k & S\geq k \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
$$

then:
$$
   E[straddle] \text = e^{-r T}\int _0{}^{\infty}\frac{payoff_{straddle} }{\sqrt{2 \pi } b S} e^{-\frac{(\log (S)-a)^2}{2 b^2}}dS
$$

But, after separating out the different pieces in the piecewise function, this becomes
$$
E[straddle] \text = e^{-r T}(\int _0{}^k\frac{(k-S) }{\sqrt{2 \pi } b S} e^{-\frac{(\log (S)-a)^2}{2 b^2}}dS
+\int _k{}^{\infty}\frac{(S-k) }{\sqrt{2 \pi } b S} e^{-\frac{(\log (S)-a)^2}{2 b^2}}dS)
$$
which is simply
$$
E[straddle] = E[C] + E[P]
$$
and, similarly
$$
E[straddle^2] =E[C^2] + E[P^2]
$$
Var[straddle] would then be:
$$
Var[straddle] = E[straddle^2] - E[straddle]^2
          = E[C^2] + E[P^2] - E[P]^2 - E[C]^2 - 2E[C]E[P]
$$
$$
Var[straddle] = Var[C] + Var[P] - 2 E[C]E[P]
$$

The second approach seems more robust to me, since we are beginning with payoff for the position and building from there. Perhaps I am missing something though.Thoughts on correct method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that
\begin{align*}
C &= e^{-rT}(S-K)^+,\\
P &= e^{-rT}(K-S)^+,
\end{align*} 
and
\begin{align*}
straddle = C+ P,
\end{align*}
then the formula
\begin{align*}
Var[straddle] = Var[C] + Var[P] - 2 E[C]E[P]
\end{align*}
is correct. However, the formula
\begin{align*}
Var[straddle] = Var[P] + Var[C] - 2\sqrt{Var[P] Var[C] }
\end{align*}
is wrong, as $C$ and $P$ are not perfectly negatively corrected. Specifically, since $CP=0$, 
\begin{align*}
Covar(C, P) &= -E(C)E(P)\\
&\neq -\sqrt{Var[P] Var[C] }.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. I knew that I was making a mistake somewhere, really appreciate you giving it a look for me.