# Higher moments of a straddle

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, moments

Following the logic of [Ben-Meir and Schiff (2012)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.3452.pdf) and this [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30138/variance-of-a-straddle-black-scholes) the first, second, third and fourth raw moments of a put are:

[image]

Similarity, for a call it is as follows:

[image]

where

[image]

and

[image]

`S` = spot price, `K` = strike price,  `r` = risk-free rate, `T` = time to maturity and `sigma` is implied volatility.

I want to know what the third and fourth raw moments of a straddle are. A straddle consist of a call and a put
If `S` > `K` at maturity. then the call option will have a value of `S` - `K`, and the put will have no value.
Likewise if `S` < `K`, the call option will have no value, and the put will be worth `S` - `K`. This can be written as:

[image]

As a result the expected final value is equal to:

[image]

This can also be written as:

[image]

Which can be simplified to:

[image]

Following this logic for the other moments I get:

[image]

According to the theory about [cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant) if two variables are independent, the `n-th`-order cumulant of their sum is equal to the sum of their `n-th`-order cumulants. Inspecting the final raw moments of the straddle it looks like this applies. However, a call and a put are not independent. When the value of a call increases/decreases, the value of a put decreases/increases, so the two option types are negatively correlated. This "fact" and the final results make me feel like I used the wrong assumptions.

**Question:** Are the the defined raw moments for a straddle correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C=(S-K)^+$ and $P=(K-S)^+$. Then it is clear, for any positive integers $i$ and $j$,
\begin{align*}
C^i P^j = 0.
\end{align*}
Consequently, for any positive integer $n$,
\begin{align*}
(C+P)^n = C^n + P^n.
\end{align*}
Your conclusion now follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check if you've made a mistake during a longish calculation like your derivation of the skew for a straddle is to numerically evaluate the original integral. It would be a one-liner in Mathematica.

Comment: thanks, Ideally, I want to know whether my assumptions about the raw moment of straddles are correct